# How to prevent a paragraph from spanning two pages

Tags: vba, ms-word

I dynamically create a word document from an excel worksheet using VBA.

One of the requirements is that all specific paragraphs be put on one page. 
Another is that specific sections need to be kept on the same page.

This project has been around for many years and continuous development has caused a lot of spaghetti code so please bite onto something before reading the code snippet down bellow.

Note: The script gets ran twice. Once, then I add in my footers then I run it again.

I just need a script snippet that pushes a paragraph to the next page if it detects that it spans two pages. Getting the correct page breaking has been an on going "put face through wall" problem so please don't be to harsh.

Col C in Agreement: Holds Page_Start (Start of multiple paragraphs that will need to be on the same page, not necasrly at the start of a page), Page_Stop (Stating that this row holds that last paragraph to be put on the same page), and New_Page (Insert a break point here)

```
Sub SetPageBreaks()
    Dim bPageStart As Boolean
    bPageStart = False

    Dim sText As String

    Dim rngFound As Word.Range

    Dim rngContent As Word.Range
    Dim sFirst As String
    Dim sLast As String

    Set rngContent = wd.Content

    bPageStart = False
    bPageEnd = False
    bSkip = False
    bNewPage = False

    Last_Row = Worksheets("Agreement").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

    DoEvents
    wd.GrammarChecked = True
    wd.SpellingChecked = True
    DoEvents

    For iRow = 1 To Last_Row

        wd.UpdateStyles

        sText = Worksheets("Agreement").Range("A" & iRow)
        IndentLevel = Worksheets("Agreement").Range("A" & iRow).IndentLevel

        If IndentLevel > 0 Then
            IndentLevel23 = 4
        End If

        If sText = "" Then
            GoTo NextIteration
        End If

        If (Worksheets("Agreement").Range("C" & iRow) <> "") Then

            Select Case Worksheets("Agreement").Range("C" & iRow)
                Case "PAGE_START"

                    bPageStart = True
                    bSkip = True

                Case "PAGE_STOP"

                    bPageEnd = True
                    bSkip = False

                Case "New_Page"
                    bNewPage = True
            End Select

        End If

        If (InStr(sText, vbLf) > 0) Then

            'This section is to deal with clauses that have line breaks inside them
            sFirst = ""
            sLast = ""
            Temp = sText

            Do While (InStr(Temp, vbLf) > 0)

                Temp = Right(Temp, Len(Temp) - InStr(Temp, vbLf))

                If Temp <> "" Then
                    sLast = Temp
                Else
                    sLast = Left(sLast, InStr(sLast, vbLf) - 1)
                End If

                If sFirst = "" Then
                    sFirst = Left(sText, InStr(sText, vbLf) - 1)
                End If
            Loop

            'end section

            Set rngFirst = FindTextInDoc(sFirst, rngContent)
            Set rngFoundStart = wd.Range(rngFirst.Start, rngFirst.Start)

            Set rngFound = FindTextInDoc(sLast, rngContent)
            Set rngFoundEnd = wd.Range(rngFound.End, rngFound.End)

        Else

            Set rngFound = FindTextInDoc(sText, rngContent)
            Set rngFoundStart = wd.Range(rngFound.Start, rngFound.Start)

            Set FndPar = rngFound.Paragraphs(1).Range
            Set rngFoundEnd = wd.Range(FndPar.End - 1, FndPar.End - 1)

        End If

        FirstChar = Left(sText, 1)
        ThirdChar = Right(Left(sText, 3), 1)

        'This is affects formatting and not page breaks. This code should be relocated.
        If (FirstChar = "(" And ThirdChar = ")") Or IndentLevel > 0 Then
            With rngFound.ParagraphFormat
                .LeftIndent = wdApp.CentimetersToPoints(0.71)
                .RightIndent = wdApp.CentimetersToPoints(0)
                .SpaceBefore = 0
                .SpaceBeforeAuto = False
                .SpaceAfter = 10
                .SpaceAfterAuto = False
                .LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceMultiple
                .LineSpacing = wdApp.LinesToPoints(1.15)
                .Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
                .WidowControl = True
                .KeepWithNext = False
                .KeepTogether = False
                .PageBreakBefore = False
                .NoLineNumber = False
                .Hyphenation = True
                .FirstLineIndent = 0 'CentimetersToPoints(0)
                .OutlineLevel = wdOutlineLevelBodyText
                .CharacterUnitLeftIndent = 4
                .CharacterUnitRightIndent = 0
                .CharacterUnitFirstLineIndent = 0
                .LineUnitBefore = 0
                .LineUnitAfter = 0
                .MirrorIndents = False
                .TextboxTightWrap = wdTightNone
            End With

        End If

        If bNewPage Then

            EndPage = wd.Range(rngFoundStart.Start, rngFoundStart.Start).Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
            Set PrvPar = rngFoundStart.Paragraphs(1).Previous(Count:=1).Range
            StartPage = PrvPar.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)

            If (EndPage = StartPage) Then
                rngFoundStart.Collapse wdCollapseStart
                rngFoundStart.InsertBreak wdPageBreak
            End If

        ElseIf bPageStart Then

            Set rngBeg = wd.Range(rngFoundStart.Start, rngFoundStart.Start)
            StartPage = rngBeg.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)

        ElseIf bPageEnd Then

            Set rngEnd = wd.Range(rngFoundEnd.End - 1, rngFoundEnd.End - 1)
            EndPage = rngEnd.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)

            Delta = EndPage - StartPage

            If Delta > 0 Then
                rngBeg.Collapse wdCollapseStart
                rngBeg.InsertBreak wdPageBreak

                With wd.Content.Find
                    .ClearFormatting
                    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
                    .Text = "^12[^12^13 ]{1,}"
                    .Replacement.Text = "^12"
                    .Forward = True
                    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                    .Format = False
                    .MatchWildcards = True
                    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
                End With

            End If


        ElseIf Not bSkip Then

            Set rngBeg = wd.Range(rngFoundStart.Start, rngFoundStart.Start)
            StartPage = rngBeg.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)

            Set rngEnd = wd.Range(rngFoundEnd.End - 1, rngFoundEnd.End - 1)
            EndPage = rngEnd.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)

            Delta = EndPage - StartPage

            If Delta > 0 Then
                rngFoundStart.Collapse wdCollapseStart
                rngFoundStart.InsertBreak wdPageBreak

            End If

        End If


        bPageStart = False
        bPageEnd = False
        bNewPage = False
NextIteration:
    Next iRow

    j = 1
'    Set myRange = wdSig.Paragraphs.Last.Range
'    myRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
'    wdSig.Bookmarks.Add _
'        Name:="BM" & j, _
'        Range:=myRange

    DoEvents
    wdSig.GrammarChecked = True
    wdSig.SpellingChecked = True
    DoEvents

    Do While (wdSig.Bookmarks.Exists("BM" & j))
        pageFirst = wdSig.Bookmarks("BM" & j - 1).Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
        pageSecond = wdSig.Bookmarks("BM" & j).Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)

        If (pageFirst <> pageSecond) Then
            Set wRng = wdSig.Bookmarks("BM" & j - 1).Range
            wRng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
            wRng.InsertBreak wdPageBreak
        End If

        j = j + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep all of a given paragraph on the same page, apply the paragraph 'Keep lines together' property. Of course, if you apply the Keep lines together' to a paragraph that has more content than will fit on a page, it won't work in that scenario.

To keep a group of paragraphs on the same page, apply the paragraph 'Keep with next' property to all except the last paragraph in the group. Of course, if you apply the 'Keep with next' property to more paragraphs than will fit on a page, it won't work in that scenario.

These properties can be used together or separately.

If you apply the paragraph 'Keep lines together' property to all paragraphs, none will cross a page break, thus obviating the need for code to test for this. Presumably, you already know how to identify which paragraphs need to be grouped.

Comment: Thank you I did not know of these properties. Most of my groupings are Titles with a paragraph, lists and defections (biggest headache: sometimes fits on one page and has big optional paragraphs) and no paragraphs and groups can be broken across two pages. It'll take me some time but I'm sure I can clean this code up with what you just told me.